# CSS Header style not applied to children

Tags: css, html

I am beginner to UI World, trying to style and arrange html components in one of my example, but I could not see the style applied for all the children of HTML header component. Here is what I have tried [Demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0aam4xn/)

```css
.page_header_style {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.title_style {
    text-align:center;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: block;
}
.user_style {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header class="page_header_style">
    <div>
        <div class="title_style">Main Title</div>
        <div>
            <ul class="user_style">
                <li>Welcome Srk</li>
                <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I would like to see the second div i.e., Welcome message & a list in the same line of the title, keeping the title at the center.

Comment: Please update the JsFiddle link. It just opens the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the "title" text in the center viewport wise, you can make the "user info" as `position:absolute`, so it will be out of the normal content flow. See the demo below.

```css
.page_header_style {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.title_style {
    text-align:center;
}
.user_style {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="page_header_style">
    <div>
        <div class="title_style">Main Title</div>
        <div>
            <ul class="user_style">
                <li>Welcome Srk</li>
                <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**JSFiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wt5f81qz/

Answer (score 1):

You should apply `float: left` to the `.title_style`, and put a clearing element (`clear:both`) on the bottom of inner content of `.page_header_style`

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/r1af39at/

Comment: Thanks, but Title should be at the center.

Answer (score 1):

**Kosturko answer regarding clearfixes**

You can alternatively use the clearfix solutions with is better than adding clear:both to an element, because in some case you'd need extra markup to apply clear:both.

The both clearfixes are applied to the immediate parent containing the floating elements.

Clearfix 1: is just to apply overflow:hidden; this works but can cause styling issues if say you wanted something to flow outside the parent using position absolute for example.

The better clearfix is to use the micro [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), best applied using a CSS preprocessor.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

By default, `div` elements have the `display: block;` attribute. Without other css styling, browsers will render them below the last block element. Try using the `display: inline-block;` as this will treat each `div` as an inline element, but treat its contents as the contents of a block element.

For example, the following css will display the main title and both list elements on the same line.

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See [w3schools's page on the display property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) for more on this.